# Beautiful Soup: find() function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
url = url_stub % (stat_id, starting_year)
page = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text.replace('n', ''), 'html.parser')
stat = html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section").find('h3').text
```

I am trying to take a BeautifulSoup object and use the find() function, but I keep getting the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first `.find()` obviously failed to find anything, so the second `.find()` had nothing to work on.

Comment: How should I change the code so that the first     .find() does not fail

Comment: @ktgo see my reply. it will help you troubleshoot this

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper is right. you may consider using exception handling or break that chain into parts to check if you got an object from `html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section")`

Answer (score 0):

to troubleshoot this better you would need to modify your code. this will help you find what part of the code is failing. however i wold also look at narrowing the html class to a single html class for testing and then if that is one of the problems find out how to add multiple class names to the find function

try this first. if it fails try a single html class name.

```
url = url_stub % (stat_id, starting_year)
page = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text.replace('n', ''), 'html.parser')

print('before stat')
stat = html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section")
print('stat worked')
print('before data')
data = stat.find('h3').text
print('after data')
```

edit: also the class_ might not be called class_ but simply class

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code ran through print('before data') but did not make it through to the print('after data'). Any advice?

Comment: `for child in stat.children:


        handle your usecase here
`

That means that you are able to get the stat object. i would inspect the object for its child objects and work from there. 

If my answer helped you solve your problem please mark it as the answer for me.

Comment: also another resource for you @ktgo http://akul.me/blog/2016/beautifulsoup-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper pointed, that is because the first `.find()` failed to find anything. To avoid the error you have to verify if your first and second find found anything:

```
if html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section"):
     if html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section").find('h3'):
         stat = html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section").find('h3').text
     else:
         stat=None
else:
    stat = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across the same function and project you're working on. You have to change:

```
stat = html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys section").find('h3').text
```

to

```
stat = html.find("div", class_="parsys mainParsys").find('h3').text
```

Also, if you're working in 3.6, you have to update:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```